# setting.php model file in extension breaks Magento! Conflict with Magento files is normal?

Tags: magento, module, settings, filenames, conflict

We created a Magento extension, and one of the models for the extension is for the extension's settings. Naming the model file "setting.php" we eventually discovered was stopping various functionality from working such as uploading images to products and shipping calculations.

Magento Version 1.5.1.0

Every time an image upload was attempted, the following error was logging to var/log/system.log:

> 2013-03-26T16:57:20+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send
>   session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at
>   /xxx/xxx/website/shop/our-extension/app/code/local/Company/Extension/Model/Setting.php:14)
>   in
>   /xxx/xxx/website/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
>   on line 115

Renaming the file to something else removed the conflict with Magento's Varien.php call. This appears to be a bug in Magento, as I could not find a documented rationale for this. Anybody have any take on this?

***Edit in response to comments:***

Our extension is only accessed in the admin backend by specifically clicking on an added extension menu. So, the call looks like it is loading the settings.php file during a call to session_start() yet trying to output something for some reason. Initially seeing our file in the output, I assumed there is no reason the system should be calling this file and therefore it is even a mistake for it to be loading it. But I suspect it is loading it as part of creating a collection of model objects that are available from the system and all extensions. Yet as you can see below, there is no output in the file.

Contents of

/xxx/xxx/website/shop/our-extension/app/code/local/Company/Extension/Model/Setting.php:14

```
<?php

class Company_Extension_Model_Setting extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
        protected function _construct()
        {
                $this->_init('extension/setting');
        }

}

?>
```

Note that there are 13 lines, but the message claims line 14 starts output.

Partial contents of config.xml:

```
    <global>
        <models>

            <extension>

                <class>Company_Extension_Model</class>

                <resourceModel>extension_mysql4</resourceModel>

            </extension>

            <extension_mysql4>
                <class>Company_Extension_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <setting>
                        <table>extension_settings</table>
                    </setting>
...
```

Comment: `Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent` means something was ouput when it is not supposed to. You should at least paste the content of `/xxx/xxx/website/shop/our-extension/app/code/local/Company/Extension/Model/Setting.php` so we could have a look at it. The `config.xml` would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for any symbols before

```
<?php
```

Maybe there is BOM symbol

Comment: Actually, I am beginning to suspect you are correct. I think renaming the file was a red herring. I think it actually worked because I re-saved the file in my editor which removed the problem character.